# How to check whether column value is null or 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = 'select column from table ...';

...


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//now i have the result
//but how to check if it's null or 0?
```

Answer (score 3):

What <strike>Pandiya</strike> was meant to say was [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$res=mysql_query(" SELECT NULL AS anullcol, 0 AS anum, '' AS emptystring ");
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($resource));
```

and read up on the '===' and '!==' operators.

C.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($var == '' || $var == NULL){
//Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isset():

```
$foo = 0;
echo isset($foo)  ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo "<br>";

$foo = null;
echo isset($foo) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

will result in

```
yes
no
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are asking if the Query has returned anything. So try using:

```
mysql_num_rows()
```

from PHP:

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

```
<?php
if ( mysql_num_rows ( $query ) == 0){
echo "duh, nothing!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe replace the null with an identifier in the select:

```
select coalesce(column, -1) as column 
from table ...
```

that way you can test for 0 or -1 (NULL).